# In the 100 blue eyes problem - why is the oracle necessary?

Tags: logical-deduction, story, meta-knowledge, blue-eyes

### The riddle

Randall Munroe (of [xkcd](https://xkcd.com) fame) has, a bit hidden on his site, [a logic puzzle](https://xkcd.com/blue_eyes.html):

> A group of people with assorted eye colors live on an island. They are
>   all perfect logicians -- if a conclusion can be logically deduced,
>   they will do it instantly. No one knows the color of their eyes. Every
>   night at midnight, a ferry stops at the island. Any islanders who have
>   figured out the color of their own eyes then leave the island, and the
>   rest stay. Everyone can see everyone else at all times and keeps a
>   count of the number of people they see with each eye color (excluding
>   themselves), but they cannot otherwise communicate. Everyone on the
>   island knows all the rules in this paragraph.
>
> On this island there are 100 blue-eyed people, 100 brown-eyed people,
>   and the Guru (she happens to have green eyes). So any given blue-eyed
>   person can see 100 people with brown eyes and 99 people with blue eyes
>   (and one with green), but that does not tell him his own eye color; as
>   far as he knows the totals could be 101 brown and 99 blue. Or 100
>   brown, 99 blue, and he could have red eyes.
>
> The Guru is allowed to speak once (let's say at noon), on one day in
>   all their endless years on the island. Standing before the islanders,
>   she says the following:
>
> "I can see someone who has blue eyes."
>
> Who leaves the island, and on what night?
>
> There are no mirrors or reflecting surfaces, nothing dumb. It is not a
>   trick question, and the answer is logical. It doesn't depend on tricky
>   wording or anyone lying or guessing, and it doesn't involve people
>   doing something silly like creating a sign language or doing genetics.
>   The Guru is not making eye contact with anyone in particular; she's
>   simply saying "I count at least one blue-eyed person on this island
>   who isn't me."
>
> And lastly, the answer is not "no one leaves."

He admits the puzzle isn't his:

> I didn't come up with the idea of this puzzle, but I've written and rewritten it over the the years to try to make a definitive version. The guy who told it to me originally was some dude on the street in Boston named Joel.

### The answer

He gives [his solution](https://xkcd.com/solution.html):

> The answer is that on the 100th day, all 100 blue-eyed people will leave. It's pretty convoluted logic and it took me a while to believe the solution, but here's a rough guide to how to get there. Note -- while the text of the puzzle is very carefully worded to be as clear and unambiguous as possible (thanks to countless discussions with confused readers), this solution is pretty thrown-together. It's correct, but the explanation/wording might not be the best. If you're really confused by something, let me know.
>
> If you consider the case of just one blue-eyed person on the island, you can show that he obviously leaves the first night, because he knows he's the only one the Guru could be talking about. He looks around and sees no one else, and knows he should leave. So: [THEOREM 1] If there is one blue-eyed person, he leaves the first night.
>
> If there are two blue-eyed people, they will each look at the other. They will each realize that "if I don't have blue eyes [HYPOTHESIS 1], then that guy is the only blue-eyed person. And if he's the only person, by THEOREM 1 he will leave tonight." They each wait and see, and when neither of them leave the first night, each realizes "My HYPOTHESIS 1 was incorrect. I must have blue eyes." And each leaves the second night.
>
> So: [THEOREM 2]: If there are two blue-eyed people on the island, they will each leave the 2nd night.
>
> If there are three blue-eyed people, each one will look at the other two and go through a process similar to the one above. Each considers the two possibilities -- "I have blue eyes" or "I don't have blue eyes." He will know that if he doesn't have blue eyes, there are only two blue-eyed people on the island -- the two he sees. So he can wait two nights, and if no one leaves, he knows he must have blue eyes -- THEOREM 2 says that if he didn't, the other guys would have left. When he sees that they didn't, he knows his eyes are blue. All three of them are doing this same process, so they all figure it out on day 3 and leave.
>
> This induction can continue all the way up to THEOREM 99, which each person on the island in the problem will of course know immediately. Then they'll each wait 99 days, see that the rest of the group hasn't gone anywhere, and on the 100th night, they all leave.
>
> Before you email me to argue or question: This solution is correct. My explanation may not be the clearest, and it's very difficult to wrap your head around (at least, it was for me), but the facts of it are accurate. I've talked the problem over with many logic/math professors, worked through it with students, and analyzed from a number of different angles. The answer is correct and proven, even if my explanations aren't as clear as they could be.
>
> User lolbifrons on reddit posted [an inductive proof](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/khhpl/reddit_what_is_your_favorite_riddle/c2kdlr6).
>
> If you're satisfied with this answer, here are a couple questions that may force you to further explore the structure of the puzzle:
>
> 1. What is the quantified piece of information that the Guru provides that each person did not already have?
> 2. Each person knows, from the beginning, that there are no less than 99 blue-eyed people on the island. How, then, is considering the 1 and 2-person cases relevant, if they can all rule them out immediately as possibilities?
> 3. Why do they have to wait 99 nights if, on the first 98 or so of these nights, they're simply verifying something that they already know?
>
> These are just to give you something to think about if you enjoyed the main solution. They have answers, but please don't email me asking for them. They're meant to prompt thought on the solution, and each can be answered by considering the solution from the right angle, in the right terms. There's a different way to think of the solution involving hypotheticals inside hypotheticals, and it is much more concrete, if a little harder to discuss. But in it lies the key to answering the four questions above.

### The question

Everybody on the island could have come to the conclusion that 'There is at least one person with blue eyes', simply by looking around, seeing 100 people with blue eyes, and realising that everybody can see at least one person with blue eyes.

**So why is it necessary for the Guru to say 'I see at least one person with blue eyes' to get the ball rolling?**

Comment: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/the-blue-eyed-islanders-puzzle-repost/

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30881/discussion-on-question-by-dwjohnston-in-the-100-blue-eyes-problem-why-is-the-o).

Comment: Y'know, unless there's a water source on that island, they're not going to make it to 100 days. And if there *is* a water source on that island, they have a means to view their own reflections. If any of these perfect logicians works this out, they'll be able to leave early, throwing off everyone else's induction-based logic.

Comment: @user867 They're not allowed to do that. It's explicitly said, "no mirrors", and it means "no mirrors". Now don't argue with me saying "a water source is not a mirror".

Comment: @cst1992 So they die of thirst around day three or so, then. I've said it before and I'll say it again: Being perfectly logical is a disability.

Comment: Maybe I don't quite understand this that well, but for me, I don't see how anyone can know for sure they have blue eyes and should leave just because someone else with blue eyes doesn't leave the first night. It's like saying "Well he didn't take his free ticket outta here last night, so I'm gonna take it for him tonight".  There's no rhyme or reason for someone to believe they have the right eye color just because a person stayed that actually does have the right color-they, themselves, actually could have brown eyes.  To me, this theorem is preposterous and incorrect.

Comment: @vapcguy - Imagine there are only two people, and you're one of them. You can see one guy with blue eyes, and now you're wondering 'do I have blue eyes as well?'. If you DIDN'T have blue eyes, then that guy would leave the first night. If you DID have blue eyes - that guy wouldn't know to leave the first night, but you would both know to leave the second night

Comment: you could have made the statement yourself 10 seconds before the guru said it, so of course it is not needed.  there are other true statements that everyone knows everyone else knows to be true, such as saying that there are 99 or more blue eyes visible, so why not assume that was said?  That then short-circuits the problem, or it invalidates it, or it reduces the guru's statement to a hint to begin a count from 1 (which is not fully logical without assumptions) - if you want my opinion, the answer doesn't stand up to 'perfect logic' rigour

Comment: although everyone can see 99 or more blue eyes, so everyone knows that everyone can see 98 or more blue eyes

Comment: If *everyone* is logical, there is no oracle needed for synchronization. As of day 1, I know that 99 other people are blue-eyed and 100 other people are brown-eyed. (Remember that I can see 99 blues and 100 browns when the oracle is present, so why not when oracle is absent?). So if no one has left the island for the past 99 days, then I know that I am also blue-eyed. I don't have "answer rights" on this site, but clearly the solution is trivial if you think backwards in time.

Comment: I don't understand this 2 blue eyed people leaving on the 2nd night. If no one left the first night, why can't a brown eyed person think he/she has blue eyes? The brown eyed person will see 2 blue eyed people and none leaving the first night. What if the brown eyed person thinks there are 3 blue eyed people including him/herself and wait for the third night to leave? What is that theorem again? Only if the blue eyed people know how many brown eyed people there are will they know to leave, and that would give extra information about how many blue eyed people there are...

Comment: On day 0, everyone deduces that the Oracle is a bit of a dick for not just telling them all their eye color and making them wait at least 99 days to get home.

Comment: There's a simpler explanation than the other answers give. They are providing information if there's 1 blue eyed. Imagine there are 3 islanders, 2 with brown eyes and 1 with blue eyes. The oracle shows up and makes its pronouncements. The 1 blue eyed person would know they were the blue eyed person and leave the next day. Now imagine 2 islanders had blue eyes and 1 had brown. They are logicians so they know after the first day that more than 1 person has blue eyes, because if just 1 did then they would have left already. Therefore it's not true, which means there must be 2 blue eyed people.

Comment: On day -1, every islander looks around and sees at least 99 blue.  Using their perfect logic, they think, "an outside observer would say they see at least one blue".  Every islander knows that.  Every islander knows that every other islander knows that.  When the guru shows up and actually makes this statement, every islander already knew that the guru *would* have made that statement.
---
Why is this not a simple counter-argument that the guru provides *NO* new information?

Comment: Because they don't know which day the guru will show up, so they are still uncertain whether there are 99 or 100 blue-eyed people, and without the oracle they have no way to start counting the same day to deduce which one is the correct number.
They need to know how many days the other inhabitants have counted up to, in order to predict their behavior. 
(AND they need to know how a hypothetical single blue-eyed person would behave on day one, in order to extend the chain of reasoning to all the other prisoners while eliminating that off-by-one error).

Comment: I used to think you could eliminate the oracle if everyone arrived to the island on the same day, and there were at least 4 blue-eyed islanders (because then, everyone is certain that all the others can see at least some blue eyes). However this is not enough, as they still need to know the mental state of all the other islanders; and this can only be traced back recursively to the hypothetical base case of 1 islander with blue eyes who knows that they have blue eyes (and no one else has them); which necessarily requires the oracle assertion, without which the exact number can't be calculated.

Comment: In short: the new information provided by the oracle is the knowledge that all the others have heard it, and have heard it on a specific day; and this information happens to be relevant for reasoning about their deduction processes.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Let's continue the induction, since the jump to 99 blue eyes does seem weird. After all, everyone knows that someone has blue eyes.

If there are 4 blue eyed-people, A will look at B,C,D, thinking :

> Maybe I don't have blue eyes (only 3 blue eyes?). In this case B must be thinking, that he may not have blue eyes either, and B is looking at C and D, whom he perceives as being the only ones to have blue eyes (since I consider the option that I don't have blue eyes), and B thinks that C is having the same reasoning. C thinks he does not have blue eyes and only D has.

Now, the issue here is that I, being A, can see that B has blue eyes. Therefore I know that C sees at least D and B as having blue eyes. But this is the reasoning of B, who does not know that he has blue eyes.

> When I project myself into the reasoning of the next person, I cannot use the knowledge I have of their eye color.

The same goes for 5 people and more. I see 4 blue-eyed people, each of which is possibly seeing only 3, and thinking that each of the other is possibly seeing only 2...

Comment: How can they "possibly see only 2"? Everyone on the island can see everyone else, so any blue eyed person will be able to see 99 blue eyed people.

Comment: @cst1992 if I see 4 blue-eyed people, there can be no more than 5. But if one of them sees only 3 blue-eyed people, that person can recurse the reasoning, not knowing that themselves hat blue eyes.

Comment: @njzk2 More explicitly, I can see 4 blues, so there are either 4 or 5 blues. If I do not have blue eyes, then a blue-eyed person can only see 3 blues, and that person must conclude that there are either 3 or 4 blues. If there are 3 blues, they will leave on the 3rd day, so if no one leaves then, there must be more than 3 blues. If I am not blue-eyed, then the 4 blues will then leave on the 4th day. If they are still around after that, then I must be blue as well, so we will all leave on the 5th day.

Comment: @cst1992 "Everyone on the island can see everyone else, so any blue eyed person will be able to see 99 blue eyed people." True, *but* any blue eyed person doesn't know if each other blue eyed person sees 99 or 98 blue eyed people. Remember also that any brown eyed person sees 100 blue eyed people and 99 brown eyed people. Any brown eyed person who isn't perfectly logical could jump to the (incorrect) conclusion that 101 people have blue eyes.

Answer (score 132):

The knowledge of each islander consists of:

- the color of the eyes of every other islander;
- any past pronouncement from the guru;
- the history of who left the island on previous days (including their eye color), which provides knowledge about others' knowledge (that either they did or did not know their own eye color on previous days).

At the beginning of the story, nobody has ever left the island and there is no past pronouncement. So the only information everyone has is the color of everybody else's eyes, and the fact that nobody has figured out their own eye color. This is a stable situation, which lasts forever. It is in fact quite intuitive that since nobody has any information that involves in any way the color of their own eyes, nobody can be certain of the color of their own eyes.

Let's say that the guru makes her pronouncement on day 0. Starting on day 0, each islander has extra information: up to n days after the pronouncement, nobody left, meaning that nobody could figure out the color of their own eyes.

Suppose that only Alice has blue eyes. Before day 0, she never knew anyone with blue eyes. On day 0, she learns that someone has blue eyes; since nobody else does, it has to be her and only her, so she takes the ferry that night.

Now suppose that only Alice and Bill have blue eyes. Before day 0, Bill already knew that there was someone with blue eyes, but **he did not know that Alice knew**. If Bill had had green eyes, Alice would have been the only blue-eyed person and would not have known. On the first night after the guru, Alice doesn't leave; this tells Bill that Alice did not know the color of her eyes, so Bill learns that she was not the only blue-eyed person. Since Bill knows that either Alice is the only blue-eyed person or Bill and Alice are the only two, Bill now knows that both he and Alice have blue eyes.

If Charlie also has blue eyes, then he follows the reasoning above. Since Alice and Bill do not leave on the second night, it follows that they are not the only two people with blue eyes, so Charlie figures out that he's the third and leaves the next night.

The information that islander X learns from the guru is not just “someone has blue eyes”, but also “**Y knows that X knows** that someone has blue eyes”, “Z knows that Y knows that X knows that someone has blue eyes”, etc. It's vital to the puzzle that **the guru's declaration is public and known to be public**. If some of the islanders didn't hear the announcement, the chain of deduction wouldn't work anymore.

Comment: Correct, the most important part is the knowledge of what the other islanders must now know, and the point in time that every other islander also knew exactly that.

Comment: So to summarize, the added information is basically a synchronization point, a manual alignment of all pieces of the puzzle into the initial state, Day 0.  This could only be otherwise achieved by mutual agreement of every islander to set a specific future date as Day 0.

Comment: @KenoguLabz No, this can't be achieved without the guru. Without the guru, the islanders will go “ok, this is day 0, so what? I don't know what others know about what others know about … what others know about the color of my eyes, so I can't infer anything”. For example, with two islanders who both have blue eyes: “Bill has blue eyes. He's not leaving because he doesn't know it. Well, he knows the color of my eyes, so he knows whether I should leave; but he isn't going to tell me, so that doesn't help me know whether I should leave.”

Comment: Hmm, so the secondary trick is that the guru is observing a sample set totally outside himself.  An arbitrary islander could have the same effect using the same statement, but in doing so he excludes himself from being observed by both himself and others.  Is that extra information, or is it part of the requisite initial state? I suppose it's just a requisite piece of information with the guru's statement: that the statement applies to some specific subset of islanders.

Comment: @KenoguLabz The islanders are not allowed to communicate (at least not in any way that would directly or indirectly provide information about one's eye color). If an islander broke this rule, that would start the clock; but the outcome would then depend on the islanders' beliefs about what rules the rulebreaker might break.

Comment: Very true.  Just tinkering with the shape of the problem at this point, figuring out what makes it tick.  In the end, you could reconstitute the problem with the islander-as-guru wrinkle, leading to a harder-to-find solution of '99 leave on day 99'.  But the problem's hard enough the first time without such nuances.

Comment: @Gilles Kenogu Labz was right the first time: the islanders could do without the guru if they agreed to a simultaneous 'knowledge reset', which is what Kenogu Labz meant by 'Day 0'. Since the islanders can all see at least 1 blue-eyed person, the only information missing is when the blue-eyed persons start counting, which Day 0 (in the 'reset' sense) provides.

Comment: @Lawrence No, this is not the only missing information. Read my next-to-last comment here again.

Comment: @Gilles Assuming you're referring to your comment about "what others know about what others know about ...", I concede there is another piece of information missing: the starting count. However, this is due to the out-by-1 problem I just commented about to user232783 in comments to the question. Even without the guru, but starting with at least 2 blue-eyed people, each islander knows the minimum starting count is 1, so that's what they use. Is there any other information that I've missed?

Comment: @Lawrence Again, no. Your “minimum starting count” is not well-defined. To reiterate: Without the guru, the islanders will go “ok, this is day 0, so what? I don't know what others know about what others know about … what others know about the color of my eyes, so I can't infer anything”. For example, with two islanders who both have blue eyes: “Bill has blue eyes. He's not leaving because he doesn't know it. Well, he knows the color of my eyes, so he knows whether I should leave; but he isn't going to tell me, so that doesn't help me know whether I should leave.”

Comment: @Gilles Ok, I define 'minimum starting count' as the consistent minimum count of blue-eyed people that all islanders deduce that any islander can consider to be present on Day 0. So with both the standard guru scenario and the 'knowledge reset', every islander knows that every other islander knows ... when every islander starts counting (and with what starting count) the number of blue-eyed people who would have left each day by the standard algorithm. Alternatively, an agreed Day 0 in the sense I used in my first comment to this answer gives equivalent information to the guru's announcement.

Comment: @Lawrence Without the guru, the minimum starting count is $n-2$ for $n$ islanders. This isn't a particularly useful concept. The minimum count of blue-eyed people that all islanders deduce that any islanders can consider that all islanders deduce that any islander can be present is $n-3$, and so on. Each time you add a layer, the minimum drops by 1. The next day, the situation is exactly the same. What the oracle changes is to say that the iterated minimum starting count is nonzero, and from then on, the minimum increases each day (because the minimum^2 has increased, because the min^3 has…).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21315/discussion-between-lawrence-and-gilles).

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for the discussion. I now agree that the broadcast oracle is required. The reasoning hinges on iterating from the case where only 1 blue-eyed person is present, and that case depends on the broadcast.

Comment: _"Bill already knew that there was someone with blue eyes, but he did not know that Alice knew"_ this only makes sense as long as the people with blue eyes are less than 3. If they are 3, each of them knows that (a) someone has blue eyes and (b) everyone of them knows that someone has blue eyes.

Comment: @Lohoris Right, if there are 3 people with blue eyes, it's between Alice, Bill and Charlie, not just between Alice and Bill, so it takes one day longer.

Comment: @Gilles I find myself in the same argument position as Lawrence and Lohoris. When you have 3+ people of the same colour, all you need is the Day 0. They all have the information that Oracle normally provides. And if everybody decides to count on Day 0 from the amount of people with blue eyes being 1 - they should be safe. Because they know everyone knows there is at least one. Everyone can see that and everyone can see everyone can see that.

Comment: @KenoguLabz, who set up this rule that without the guru they don't know what the others know? It appears that this supposition is being invented out of whole cloth by those who are attempting to defend the Guru's necessity to the initiation of the cascade.  Where is it written that they have any doubts about the knowledge of the other islanders? Quite the contrary, we have to assume that they all KNOW that they all see 99 (+?1) blue eyes. And given that fact they would indeed all start their own count on the first day they ever got to the island.

Comment: I think the reason it's required is to ensure they are all focusing on the exact same property as their inductive basis.  If the guru did not say 'blue eyes', what are they counting? Brown eyes? Brown hair? Freckles? There's no shared basis, and the communication breaks down.  As @Lawrence stated well, it's vital that it be a 'broadcast oracle', someone who guarantees that one concrete piece of information is distributed to all participants, so all have identical understanding of the initial conditions and inductive context.

Comment: @GeniaS. One of the premises of the puzzle is “No one knows the color of their eyes.”. You cannot assume that “they all KNOW that they all see 99 (+?1) blue eyes”: not only is there no basis for that in the hypotheses, it in fact directly contradicts the hypotheses.

Comment: @Gilles, you're misunderstanding the puzzle (or I'm misunderstanding you). The *only thing any individual doesn't know is the color of their own eyes. Everyone knows exactly how many eye colors other than their own there are. Without this they wouldn't be able to do their logical deduction once they've been told that someone sees someone with blue eyes.

Comment: @GeniaS. Yes, everyone knows how many eye colors other than there own there are. However, they don't know everything the others know. Alice knows the color of Bill's eyes but Alice does not know what eye colors Bill see.

Comment: @Gilles, I am trying to understand (as you're not the first person to articulate it this way) how anyone can be under the impression that anyone can think that anyone can think that anyone can think... (etc) that there are less than (number of blue eyed people - 2). It seems to me that the misapprehension ends at the 3rd person (assuming there are more than 4 people with blue eyes).

Comment: @GeniaS. So you understand why the oracle is necessary in the 3-people case but not in the 4-people case? How does adding Dominique to the party somehome let Alice know the color of her eyes?

Comment: @Gilles, I posted my own answer to this question which (maybe) helps explain the nature of my confusion which I'm guessing is not unique. Thanks very much for helping me sort through it.

Comment: The announcement being public and the guru knowing someone has blue eyes, and everyone knowing that the guru knows someone has blue eyes, doesn't really matter.  There are 100 blue-eyed people, and everyone can and has probably already seen at least one blue-eyed person and probably already knows this bit of trivia. Seems to me the information is moot and wouldn't tell me anything new about myself.

Comment: @vapcguy The information doesn't tell you anything about yourself. It tells you something about what others know about what others know about … about yourself. Work it out on cases where the chain isn't 100 long: with 2 people, then with 3.

Comment: @Gilles It only works for 2 people + guru. If guru says "I see blue eyes", and guru has green eyes and person B has brown, you know you have blue. But when there are more people that have your color, too, you cannot gain the knowledge about your own color - only that they know others have blue eyes, too, but that was in the given premise, that everyone can see everyone else, so of course they see the eye color - they are not blind and can obviously see the other's eyes. Them knowing what color I have does not help me to know my color & leave the island when so many others have it, too.

Comment: @vapcguy The reasoning works for any number of people. The more people you have, the more meta you need to get: “A knows B's eye color”, “A knows that B knows C's eye color”, “A knows that B knows that C knows D's eye color”, etc. Read my answer, or Genia's (who had the same difficulty as you at first).

Comment: @Gilles We already know that everyone can see everyone, so we already know that everyone knows each other's color.  It's part of the given statement and not new information. And it would not matter who knows I have blue eyes, if I cannot infer/surmise what color I have based on them knowing.

Answer (score 58):

Every blue-eyed person sees 99 blue-eyed people. Since they don't know that they have blue eyes, they suspect it might be the case that every other blue-eyed person can only see 98 blue-eyed people, and if those people only see 98 blue-eyed people, they might think that each of *them* only see 97 blue-eyed people. And so it continues, until someone considers a hypothetical situation in which someone sees no blue-eyed people. Then the guru, in this hypothetical, really does make a difference.

So the essential piece of information the Guru provides is that everyone knows that everyone knows that everyone knows that [... etc. ...] everyone knows that there is someone on the island with blue eyes. This enables everyone to discard that nested hypothetical.

It might be easier if we assign everyone numbers. People 1 to 100 have blue eyes. Person 1 sees 99 people with blue eyes, so suspects that Person 2 might see only 98 people with blue eyes, in which case Person 2 would think that Person 3 might only be able to see 97 people with blue eyes, in which case they would think that Person 4 might only be able to see 96… all this speculating is unravelled when everyone finds out that if Person 100 could not see any blue eyes, then Person 100 would be able to leave, so if Person 99 could only see one set of blue eyes, Person 99 would be able to leave after they didn't, so… etc.

---

Perhaps this is enlightening: if the Guru went to each person individually, and told them each in secret that there was a person with blue eyes, then it would not help: they would truly have learned nothing. The Guru saying that someone has blue eyes does not change anyone's mind about whether or not anyone has blue eyes. But that's not all everyone gets from the situation: not only did everyone hear the announcement, everyone saw that everyone else heard the announcement, and everyone saw that everyone saw that etc. Everyone finds out something about other people's state of knowledge.

Comment: +1 for the numbering, that is a really helpful way of thinking about it.

Comment: But, why would Person 2 think Person 3 can only see 97 people with blue eyes? Everyone knows everyone can see at least 98 people with blue eyes.

Comment: @ChrisJefferson: It's not Person 2 who thinks Person 3 can only see that. It's a hypothetical Person 2 that Person 1 imagines might exist, if Person 1 has brown eyes.

Comment: @ChrisJefferson Yes, everyone knows everyone can see at least 98 people with blue eyes. But not everyone knows that everyone knows that everyone can see at least 98.

Comment: But why not? I don't see why I (and everyone) can't deduce that fact immediately (assuming everyone is perfectly logical, and if they aren't, the whole thing falls apart).

Comment: @ChrisJefferson: They are indeed all perfectly logical. If there were 99 people with blue eyes, blue-eyed people would think that there might be 98, and that other blue-eyed people might only be able to see 97. With 100 of them, blue-eyed people think that the situation I just described might be the case.

Comment: The key is that none of *them* know there are 100 blue eyed people. That information is only revealed to us the reader.

Comment: Why do the numbers go down?  Why would Person 2 think 98 people have blue eyes?  Why would Person 99 think only one person has blue-eyes?  This logic doesn't make any sense - especially when the puzzle says that everyone can SEE everyone else and SEE the 99 other blue-eyed people (or 100, if they are brown-eyed).

Comment: @vapcguy: It's not about what Person 2 thinks. It's about what Person 1 imagines Person 2 thinking. Person 1 sees 99 blue-eyed people. For all Person 1 knows, those might be the only 99 blue-eyed people. Thus Person 1 thinks blue-eyed people might only be able to see 98 other blue-eyed people.

Comment: Sure. Everyone knows that everyone knows that everyone can see at least 98 other blue eyed people. So how does the guru's statement make any difference? That is what tripped me up.

Comment: @Yablargo every time you add an "everyone knows" you also decrement the number by 1. At some point the number will reach zero, and that's where the guru is adding information, because by saying this *publically* at a big meeting, they're not just saying "someone has blue eyes" they are also implicitly saying "now everyone knows that everyone knows that ..." etc. and ruling out the zero hypothetical.

Comment: I understand the process you describe, but I guess my beef is that any villager can see that for any other villager V, V sees 98 or more other blue eyed people. Every villager V is perfectly logical, every villager V knows that every other villager V can see everyone, and that they are also perfectly logical. I don't see how the "everyone knows.." rountable holds up when every villager clearly sees the group. If I look at V=1, I KNOW V=1 can see everyone else, including me. Repeat for V=0-200

Answer (score 35):

The whole process is inductive, so it needs a starting point. If there were only one blue-eyed person, he would never know that there is "at least one person with blue eyes," so he would not go the first night. If there are only two, neither of them can know whether the other doesn't go the first night because he only sees brown eyes, so they don't know if they should go the second night. A third wouldn't be able to know if the first two hadn't gone because they only see one each or two, and so on.

When the oracle makes his statement, it ensures that a hypothetical lone blue-eyed person would know he is the one, which allows the induction to begin.

Comment: But this doesn't answer the question in my opinion.  At the start, there are 100 people with blue eyes and they all see 99 people with blue eyes.  Why does the proclamation of the guru make a difference?  They can all see that there are others with blue eyes, so the guru's proclamation seems useless.

Comment: @Trenin Induction needs a starting point. In this case, the starting point is a hypothetical single blue-eyed person, who could not know that there exists a blue-eyed person.

Comment: I know that it needs a starting point, but the question that OP poses is why do you need the guru to provide it?  Everyone can see that there are people with blue eyes, so what added information has the guru given by telling everyone that there is at least one?

Comment: @Trenin The base case, the single islander with blue eyes, does *not* know there exists a blue-eyed islander. The guru's statement would give that person information, allowing him to start the inductive process.

Comment: But when there are 100 islanders, who is this single islander?  There is nothing to differentiate them.  So the guru's proclamation is not given any new information to the 100 blue-eyed people since they all know everyone can see at least one blue eyed person.

Comment: If you were in a room and saw two people had blue eyes, and I came in and said "There is at least one person with blue eyes" have I told you (or anyone else) anything they didn't already know?  Have I added any new information?

Comment: What the OP has drawn attention to is the fact that at the start of day 1, before the guru says anything, every person can tell that there is at least one person with blue eyes - they all can see at least 99 others.  So why does the fact that they guru says "there is at least one" make any difference?  It is not new information to anyone.  In fact, why can't they all say to themselves "there is at least one person with blue eyes" to get the ball rolling inductively without the guru?

Comment: They can't get the ball rolling without the guru because *if there were only one of them, he could not get the ball rolling by himself.*

Comment: But the point is, there is not only one of them.  There are 100 of them.  The information the guru gives is something they already know, so why do they need it?

Comment: I think carefully phrased the information given would be "if there were one blue-eyed person, they would leave tonight."

Comment: But even that information is something everyone already knows or can deduce without the guru's help.  I agree that the guru is definitely giving crucial information, but I think this answer is incomplete, or at least doesn't explain what new information everyone gets from the guru's proclamation.

Comment: Why do you think everyone knows when a single blue-eyed person would leave the island?

Comment: @Trenin: They all knew that at least one had blue eyes, but it wasn't [common knowledge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_knowledge_(logic)) until the oracle said so. This is the new piece of information. If you don't believe me, think about it this way: If I see 'x' people with blue eyes, I'll think is possible that I have brown eyes and blue eyed people see 'x - 1' blue eyed people. Which would make them think is possible that they have brown eyes and other blue eyed people only see 'x - 2' blue eyed people. Which ... would make someone think no one has blue eyes.

Comment: @Juan Now we are getting somewhere! This makes it more inline with the other answers, but simply saying it is the inductive base is not enough in my opinion.  One has to identify what is the new information that is being added by this statement, and the fact that there is at least one person with blue eyes is not new information to anyone.  The fact that everyone - even the hypothetical lone blue eyed person - would know is the key.

Comment: @Trenin Yes. If she would've gone around saying it in secret to each islander it would've not had the same effect.

Comment: @Juan thanks (&hand thanks Trenin), this adding really helped me getting a better grip of that riddle.

Comment: @Trenin, please elaborate. How is this *not common knowledge? Are you just assuming it's not common knowledge? I've seen various versions of this puzzle and in at least one these islanders keep perfect count of everyone's eye color and they know that everyone else does too (since there's a rule about deportation that they all religiously adhere to).  So... what part of this would imply that anyone would have any doubts about what anyone else is aware of - namely - that there are indeed (at least) 99 blue eyed people on the island.

Comment: @GeniaS.  I am not sure you are asking the right person.  I know it is common knowledge.  My problem was with this particular answer because it did not give a satisfactory reason why the statement "there is at least one person with blue eyes" was critical to solving the problem.

Comment: @Trenin, I understand. I'm arguing that the OP's assumption is correct. The Guru's proclamation is useless and the population would have started their logical countdown on day 1 upon first glance at one another.

Comment: A person knowing someone has blue eyes, IF they were the only one, would yes, tell that person they are the blue-eyed one and should go, if all they can see are brown-eyed people.  But when there are 100 blue-eyed people, this information doesn't do anyone any good.

Answer (score 32):

The only explanation I've seen that's sufficiently precise to be satisfying is [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/490546/9693) to the corresponding [question on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489308/blue-eyes-a-logic-puzzle). The key fact that the "oracle" (guru) gives you, that you didn't have before, is that "(everybody knows)<sup>N</sup> there is at least one blue-eyed person" for any value of N. In particular, you need it to be true for N=100, but the "induction process" starting from direct observation only gives you the result up to 99 levels of "(everybody knows)". The guru really is giving additional information that you don't already know: not information about the existence of a blue-eyed person, but information about everyone's knowledge of what each other know.

In particular, explanations that claim the guru is just needed as a starting point for counting days are wrong. The guru's statement, and everyone's awareness of it, are really needed in order for anyone to draw a conclusion about their own eye color.

Comment: Aaron McDaid's [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489308/blue-eyes-a-logic-puzzle/490546#comment2030408_490546) to that answer really made me think.

Comment: Actually, everyone can see everyone else, according to the puzzle, so they can already see 99 other blue-eyed people, if they have blue eyes, or 100 blue-eyed people, if they have brown-eyes.  No new information is provided.

Comment: @vapcguy: Your comment has nothing to do with the answer and is just repeating the OP's original confusion. Being informed about other people's eye colors is not the new information. Being informed about other people's knowledge about other people's knowledge about other people's knowledge about .... other people's knowledge of eye colors is the new information.

Comment: @R.. Again, no, I disagree. It is not really new to know other people's knowledge, either. Whether the guru says it or not, everyone can already see 99 other blue-eyed people, if they have blue eyes, or 100 blue-eyed people, if they have brown-eyes. Whether anyone else *KNOWS* others know this is irrelevant and doesn't yield the answer given - they can already see it for themselves there are blue-eyed people around! AGAIN, no new information is presented, except to tell us the guru isn't blind - but most people will already assume that from the premise that everyone can see each other.

Comment: @vapcguy: This isn't a matter of agreeing or disagreeing. You're just wrong. Study the version of the problem with $N=2$ or $N=3$ and it should be easier to understand what the new information is.

Comment: @R.. Yes, people keep saying that.  It only works if there are 2 people (including you) + guru, and you are the one with blue eyes. You see the guru with green, the other person with brown, and you will know you have blue eyes.  If there are 3 people (including you) + guru and just one of those people has blue eyes, you do not learn that you have blue eyes and can leave.  It falls flat.

Comment: @vapcguy: You're still missing the point and I can't spend forever trying to explain it to you. If my answer isn't clear to you, find somebody else's explanation. The math.SE answer I linked is the most precise and detailed one I've found and if you take the time to understand it, it should clear up all your confusion.

Comment: @R.. Thanks, I read it.  Mathematically, if you depend on quantifying "Common Knowledge" through an equation that can only come through assuming the guru is giving "N" new information everytime someone sees others not leaving, yes, it makes sense. But logically, from a real-life viewpoint and knowing Common Knowledge comes from direct observation, not equations/assumptions/knowing what others know, it doesn't. No one can assume they can leave just because others don't, if you have any more than 1 person with blue eyes. Everyone can see each other and will see blue eyed people everywhere.

Comment: @vapcguy: This assumption stated in the problem is essential: *They are all perfect logicians -- if a conclusion can be logically deduced, they will do it instantly.* The assumption that they all know this about each other is essential too. Perhaps that's the part that's contrary to your real-life viewpoint and why the discrepancy is confusing.

Comment: @R.. Yeah, thanks, I saw that, too, and believe that to be the true lynchpin, as well. Mathematicians will see that and draw up the formulas of elimination-I saw that statement and said, there's no way they can logically, really, *ACTUALLY* believe they have blue eyes and leave, just because someone else doesn't leave - that was just absurd and illogical to me, since no true conclusion could really be made by that, except that they just didn't know their own eye color, as to why that person didn't leave. Someone can't REALLY infer they have blue eyes just because the other person didn't leave.

Comment: @vapcguy: They can only draw conclusions about what one another will do, based on the knowledge that they all have perfect logic and act on it, when they can draw sufficient conclusions about what information each other have. This is how the whole "$\textrm{(everybody knows)}^N(...)$" matter arises. It's not that they would solve the problem differently without "perfect logical behavior"; rather, the problem just wouldn't make any sense or be interesting because they wouldn't have information to act on or a well-defined condition to let them leave.

Comment: @R.. And that's why it doesn't make sense to me, since "perfect logic" must be subjective to the person employing it, since I don't see how it's "perfectly logical" for someone to think they can leave just because someone else doesn't, just because they *know* "someone" must have blue eyes, and that everyone knows someone must have blue eyes, based on the guru's statement, when of course they can already see 99 or 100 others with blue eyes, too - not just the brown-eyed person beside them, and know that everyone else is not blind (I would assume from the givens) and can already see that.

Comment: @vapcguy: Everyone's acting on their knowledge in order to leave when they can is also an assumption of the problem. If "subjectivity vs logic" bothers you, the problem can be restated in terms where the people are all replaced by tasks on a computer, with appropriate constraints on their programming. I'll leave actually making that restatement as an exercise for someone else to work out, though. :-)

Comment: @R.. Yeah, only that program would have to have a rule that lets someone leave the next day as long as they see someone else that hasn't, all because "someone" must have blue eyes..."guess it's me...[leaves]"  Sure, you can have a rule like that - I just didn't find the reasoning for that rule to exist as very logical at all (they could have purple-polka-dotted eyes, for all they know), so yeah, that's what bothered me.

Comment: @vapcguy: No, that program would not satisfy the equivalent problem. A solution to the equivalent problem would have all the programs "leave" on the 100th day, and the rulekeeper who decides if they can leave would be evaluating some sort of proof of their eligibility to leave based on logic equivalent to the solution to the problem with human islanders. BTW if you think "they could have purple-polka-dotted eyes" makes any difference to the problem (note: no knowledge of a limited set of eye colors is necessary to the problem) I think you're still seriously misunderstanding it.

Comment: @R.. Whether they are eligible to leave incrementally, as they decide that "someone else hasn't figured it out & gone, so I should go" (as found on another thread), or all at once on the 100th day-which seems silly because they could just as easily leave on day 1 or 1000 as day 100-I think is immaterial because no one's explained (at least in a way that makes sense, logically, to me) what the catalyst is that lets them be able to determine their own eye color and leave, beside a formula that says *(everybody knows)^N* which also doesn't make sense because they know everyone's color from day 1.

Comment: @vapcguy: Whatever other thread you're looking at is wrong, because nobody can leave without knowing their own eye color, and there is provably no way to get that information incrementally. What you're missing is still that knowing everybody else's eye colors is not sufficient to know your own. You also need knowledge about what all the other people know, which (by assumption) you can infer from their action or lack thereof.

Comment: @vapcguy: When you observe 99 blue-eyed people, you know there are at least 99 blue-eyed people, but you don't know whether they are all aware of that fact or not. If you're not blue-eyed yourself, then the others will only see 98 blue-eyed people. Thus, the others all know there are at least 98 blue-eyed people, but they don't know that each other know that. From your perspective, since they don't know their own eye colors, they can only know that each other know there are at least 97 blue-eyed people. And so on. This is the $(\textrm{everybody knows})^N$ that pops up.

Comment: If you look at a simpler example with $n=2$ (2 blue-eyed people), everybody knows there's at least one blue-eyed person, but a person who only sees one blue-eyed person does not know that the other blue-eyed person sees any blue-eyed people (because they don't know their own eye color). Thus, the statement "everybody knows that everybody knows there's at least one blue-eyed person" is false. It takes the oracle saying this, **in a public way that everyone is aware that everyone else knows**, in order for "everybody knows that everybody knows there's at least one blue-eyed person" to be true.

Comment: In the $n=100$ case, it really takes 100 levels of "everybody knows" indirection to make the conclusion, rather than just 2 levels like in the $n=2$ case. You can try to understand that via the induction in the linked answer on math.SE, or just by working out the $n=3$, $n=4$, etc. cases by hand until you're satisfied that you understand the pattern.

Comment: @R.. I've seen both answers, incremental & all-at-once. Neither made sense. The islanders knowing blue-eyed people exist shouldn't matter-the givens state they can all see each other. So assuming no one is blind, shouldn't they therefore already know everyone can see everyone else's color? And I'll humor you, say they now learn this for the 1st time. What they learned was only that at least 1 person has blue-not the total. I follow your reasoning from 99 to 98, but don't see the number magically going down from 98 to 97. If you're not blue, and see 99 blues, yes, one of them sees 98 blues. But

Comment: you don't then turn around and only see 97, and they don't then somehow only see 97 when they saw 98 a min ago (because there are 99 total, and they are one of the total). The pattern only goes down to a steady-state of knowledge, not some endless spiral, because the # of blue-eyed people doesn't change, nor does the knowledge they had once the guru says there's at least one blue-eyed person running around.  With 2 people, it really depends on the number of people with blue-eyes. If there is only one, the person with blue eyes learns they have blue eyes, when they see the other with brown.

Comment: You are right that this blue-eyed person will not know they have blue eyes until the guru's statement, and won't know at all if both are blue-eyed, but we have a system of 100 blues and 100 browns, not 1 brown-eyed and 1 blue-eyed, so it no longer works like that unless each blue eyed person can only see one brown eyed person - but the givens say everyone can see everyone else, so they'll all be able to see many blue eyed people, already.

Comment: @vapcguy: I'm sorry, I can't keep explaining this over and over. Something is wrong in your thought process and I'm not sure what it is, but you're not going to find it until you stop insisting there's something wrong with the solution and instead try to understand why it's right.

Comment: The gurus's statement was in the set of true statements she could make before she said it, therefore any logical reasoning could have been made before she said it - she did not tell anyone that anyone else did/didn't know anything.  we also know that everyone can see 99 or more blue eyes, therefore everyone knows that everyone else knows that the statement 'i can see at least 99 blue eyes' is a true statement - in which case people seeing 98 would leave (if they existed), so on the second day everyone seeing 99 would leave

Comment: @Cato: I'm not going to keep explaining this to people who are wrong. Go read.

Comment: I've been avidly reading it - your statement #The guru really is giving additional information that you don't already know:# but he is not! Why not start at the strongest know truth?  Everyone knows that everyone can see 98 or more blue eyes (I make it) = people don't have to follow your scheme - remember the original question rules

Comment: @Cato: Hint: you're completely missing the exponents around (everybody knows).

Answer (score 19):

I think considering it backwards might actually be the easier way to understand it.

A given blue-eyed person does not want to leave, so he hopes he has brown eyes and assumes he has brown eyes.  He sees 99 blue-eyed people.  Because he has assumed he does not have brown eyes himself, he must assume all of those other blue eyed people see 98 other blue eyed people.  (*In his mind, he has removed himself from the set of blue eyed people.*)

(The **fact** that all the blue eyed people *actually* see 99 other blue eyed people is separate from the **belief** the first person holds that those people see 98 others.)

The first person then goes on to reason that a given one of the 98 will see only 97 others.  So, the first person believes there are 99 total, and in the mind of the first person is an imaginary second person who believes there are 98 total.  And so on.

The entire stack of one mind thinking about what is in the mind of another person who is thinking about what is in the mind of another person exists entirely in the mind of the first person.  That's how the state of *imagined knowledge* can get so far from the reality that everyone can physically observe.

The rest of the induction has been explained already, so I'll just amplify the two points I wanted to add to the discussion with this answer:

- Each person is in turn *removing himself from the set* of blue eyed people (until his hypothesis is contradicted on day 100). That's why the numbers go down 99, 98, etc.
- We are dealing with nested levels of imagined minds thinking about other imagined minds (like the nested dreams in Inception).  The 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc. levels are "virtual people" (like nested virtual machines) and that's how they see can differ from what is physically observed.

Comment: Somehow I missed then when I wrote my answer. It's really good, and provides a non-confusing way of thinking about the problem without needing any mathematical formalities. Excellent answer.

Answer (score 17):

The colour of the guru's eyes is not relevant. **The guru is allowed to speak about eyes and nobody else is.** If any blue eyed person said "I can see someone with blue eyes" where everyone on the island could hear it, the same thing would happen. Also if any brown eyed person did. The moment a blue-eyed person hears that **someone else** can see some blue eyes, and those blue-eyed people know it, the clock starts ticking. Once I hear that and I see N blue eyed people, if they haven't left after N days it's because they are including me in their count of N. Therefore I have to leave on day N+1. It even works if they wake up one morning and find "at least one person has blue eyes" scrawled on the mirror in lipstick, except for them not having any mirrors.

Comment: I think that's a bit of a nit, @Taemyr, but I've edited

Answer (score 16):

There are a lot of explanations for this, and certainly also a lot of debate over this question as the problem is extremely counterintuitive. Therefore, no explanation I could give or anybody could give will come close to satisfying everyone, but I will try anyway.

---

Although every islander knows that there is at least one person in the island with blue eyes, the blue-eyed people do *not* know whether there are 99 or 100 people with blue eyes on the island.

The guru coming and saying there is a person on the island with blue eyes allows them to start the chain of inferences alluded to in the solution and conclude that if everybody does not leave in 99 days, they are a person with blue eyes as well.

The reason they cannot start this chain of inferences themselves boils down to the fact that although they see somebody with blue eyes, they cannot determine how many days to wait (either 98 and I am not blue-eyed, or 99 and I am blue-eyed) because they do not know the total number of blue-eyed people on the island. You need somebody *outside* their group to come and tell them that there is at least one person with blue eyes, so that you have the inductive base case of one blue-eyed person to build on top of and determine how many days to wait.

Comment: But why couldn't they make that inductive base themselves?  After all, they each see many blue eyed people, and they all know that everyone else sees those blue eyed people, so why couldn't they say to themselves "gee, everyone can see at least one blue eyed person, so everyone knows there is at least one blue eyed person"?

Comment: But why would they start counting on any particular day? Without a set starting day, a brown-eyed person could say, "I see 100 blue-eyed people, and no one has left in the last 100 days, therefore I must have blue eyes," and get on the ferry that night, *even though he has brown eyes*.

Comment: This answer seems to assume there is only one person leaving every night.  The answer given by the OP is that on the 100th day, all 100 people leave at once.

Answer (score 15):

As you did, let's reduce it to the case of three people for clarity's sake.

Aaron, Bob, and Charlie have blue eyes. No guru says anything.

Aaron thinks: If Bob sees only Charlie with blue eyes, then Bob knows after the first night, viz after Charlie doesn't leave, that Bob has blue eyes.

Er, no. That'd be true if the guru said someone has blue eyes. But that's not true now: Charlie's not leaving doesn't mean anything, as no one has told him he has blue eyes. So (in Aaron's mind) Bob doesn't, even if he sees only Charlie with blue eyes, know after Charlie doesn't leave the first night that Bob has blue eyes.

Answer (score 12):

Let's take the case where there are 3 blue eyed people. each blue eyed person sees two blue eyed people but that is not enough for him/her to realize they have blue eyes. for that fact to be inferred he needs to observe the two blue eyed people he sees not leaving after two days.
and the only reason he would expect them to leave in two days is because he observed them listening to the remark that "there is at least one blue eyed person".

If the information was not shared to all at the same time there would be no reason for anyone to expect the group of blue eyed people to leave at any point.

If you see N blue eyed people around you expect them to all leave N days after the statement. if the information isn't shared there would be no reason for that expectation and therefore it would be impossible to infer your own eye color.

Answer (score 11):

The Guru's information makes the blue-eyed-people special. It is a bit easier to understand if you imagine the Guru saying "those with blue eyes may go".

Then on day 1, you see nobody leaving, so you know nobody knows his own eyecolor, so you can conclude that at least 2 persons must have blue eyes.

Then on day 2, you see nobody leaving, so you know nobody knows his own eyecolor, so you can conclude that at least 3 persons must have blue eyes.

...
Then on day 99, you see nobody leaving, so you know nobody knows his own eyecolor, so you can conclude that at least 100 persons must have blue eyes. But if you have blue eyes and you see that there are only 99 other blue-eyed persons, you know you are the lucky #100. So you'll leave at day 100.

If the Guru wasn't necessary, the people with brown eyes could also leave the island sooner or later. But there is no way for them to assure they don't have red eyes, or any other color. If only two colors existed, they could all go if the Guru only said which color should leave first.

Basically, the info given by the Guru is NOT "there is someone here with blue eyes". Everybody knows that already, since everybody sees two blue-eyed persons and everybody knows those two can see each other.

It is also NOT "everybody knows that there is someone here with blue eyes". It actually is "everybody knows, that everybody knows, that everybody knows, ... [repeat 99 times] that someone has blue eyes".

Comment: I think the problem here is that somebody will make the argument that everyone should already know _that_ after 99 days on the island themselves. The information that the guru introduces is completely hypothetical.

Comment: I love the fact I just saw @JoeZ. talking about 99 problems.....

Comment: in case someone is scrolling through this question years later, this answer might be misleading... saying "those with blue eyes may go" is not sufficient because it does not provide the common knowledge that someone has blue eyes; saying that to an island with 1 blue-eyed person will not prompt them to go because it is possible for the guru to say that while everyone has brown eyes

Answer (score 11):

## The oracle disproves a nested hypothetical.

I'll try to prove this from the top down without using induction.

First, a definition:

**Person(n)** is the n'th blue-eyed person. We number the blue-eyed people 1 to 100 without loss of generality, with each person being Person(1) from their own perspective. Those without blue eyes are not relevant to this proof and are ignored.

**H(n)** is the n'th nested layer of hypothetical worlds with each person assuming their own eyes are non-blue at every layer.

- **H(0)** is our perspective looking at the puzzle from the outside. It contains 100 people with blue eyes.
- **H(1)** is what we imagine Person(1) sees, and contains 99 people of blue eyes.
- **H(2)** is what we imagine Person(1) imagines Person(2) sees if Person(1) does not have blue eyes. It contains 98 pairs of blue eyes.
- **H(3)** is what we imagine Person(1) imagines Person(2) imagines Person(3) sees, if Person(1) and Person(2) both assume that they don't have blue eyes. It contains 97 pairs of blue eyes.
- **H(100)** is what we imagine Person(1) imagines Person(2) imagines Person(3) imagines... Person(99) imagines Person(100) sees, if Person([1, 99]) assume that their eyes are non-blue. It contanis 0 pairs of blue eyes.
- **H(101)** is what we imagine Person(1) imagines Person(2) imagines Person(3) imagines... Person(99) imagines Person(100) imagines that the Guru sees, if Person([1, 100]) assume that their eyes are non-blue. It contanis 0 pairs of blue eyes.

Prior to the Guru's statement, H(101) is conceivable to Person(1) - not that it is *true*, but Person(1) believes that Person(2) believes that Person(3) believes... ...that Person(99) believes that Person(100) believes that it might be true.

After the Guru's statement, H(101) is no longer conceivable. Since H(101) is no longer conceivable, Person(100) in H(100) would leave on the next night. Since they don't, H(100) becomes impossible. Since no one leaves the night after, H(99) becomes impossible. Each night, another layer of nested H(n) becomes impossible, until on the final night, H(1) becomes impossible and everyone simultaneously realizes that H(0) is the only possibility remaining.

#### The full definition of H(101)

Here is the fully expanded of H(101), which the Guru's statement renders impossible.

> H(101) is what we imagine Person(1) imagines Person(2) imagines Person(3) imagines) imagines Person(4) imagines Person(5) imagines Person(6) imagines Person(7) imagines Person(8) imagines Person(9) imagines Person(10) imagines that Person(11) imagines that Person(12) imagines that Person(13) imagines that Person(14) imagines that Person(15) imagines that Person(16) imagines that Person(17) imagines that Person(18) imagines that Person(19) imagines that Person(20) imagines that Person(21) imagines that Person(22) imagines that Person(23) imagines that Person(24) imagines that Person(25) imagines that Person(26) imagines that Person(27) imagines that Person(28) imagines that Person(29) imagines that Person(30) imagines that Person(31) imagines that Person(32) imagines that Person(33) imagines that Person(34) imagines that Person(35) imagines that Person(36) imagines that Person(37) imagines that Person(38) imagines that Person(39) imagines that Person(40) imagines that Person(41) imagines that Person(42) imagines that Person(43) imagines that Person(44) imagines that Person(45) imagines that Person(46) imagines that Person(47) imagines that Person(48) imagines that Person(49) imagines that Person(50) imagines that Person(51) imagines that Person(52) imagines that Person(53) imagines that Person(54) imagines that Person(55) imagines that Person(56) imagines that Person(57) imagines that Person(58) imagines that Person(59) imagines that Person(60) imagines that Person(61) imagines that Person(62) imagines that Person(63) imagines that Person(64) imagines that Person(65) imagines that Person(66) imagines that Person(67) imagines that Person(68) imagines that Person(69) imagines that Person(70) imagines that Person(71) imagines that Person(72) imagines that Person(73) imagines that Person(74) imagines that Person(75) imagines that Person(76) imagines that Person(77) imagines that Person(78) imagines that Person(79) imagines that Person(80) imagines that Person(81) imagines that Person(82) imagines that Person(83) imagines that Person(84) imagines that Person(85) imagines that Person(86) imagines that Person(87) imagines that Person(88) imagines that Person(89) imagines that Person(90) imagines that Person(91) imagines that Person(92) imagines that Person(93) imagines that Person(94) imagines that Person(95) imagines that Person(96) imagines that Person(97) imagines that Person(98) imagines that Person(99) imagines that Person(100) imagines that the Guru sees, if Person([1, 100]) assume that their eyes are non-blue. It contanis 0 pairs of blue eyes.

After the Guru's statement, no one is imagining that hypothetical anymore (and this is common knowledge).

Comment: Yes! This puzzle is too rarely taken by the horns
(top-down recursion, as opposed to catch-a-tiger-by-the-tail
bottom-up induction).  Please also see the
[answer that spurred this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/100236/),
at a closed (just temporarily I hope) question.

Answer (score 9):

I started writing my definitive explanation for how everyone is actually wrong about the necessity of the Oracle's proclamation and in the process finally explained to myself why, in fact, it's essential.

Possibly not adding anything new to the list of answers (how ironic is that??) I'll throw in my explanation.

This is highly unintuitive, but the way that the eye logic is deduced starts with the accusation that someone has blue eyes. The immediate response to that accusation is "is it me?" (by everyone on the island).

As we know if we reduce this down to 2 people if they both have blue eyes they each say (to themselves) "I also see someone with blue eyes" and wind up sitting there for an extra day.

But their thought process is "what is the other person thinking? - they *know that there's a blue eyed person on the island and they know that I know that there's a blue eyed person on the island and therefore if I'm not moving it must be because they have blue eyes".

So, what happens if you don't have the announcement?

Well, with one and two people it's self evident that looking at no one or one other person offers no useful info.

However, with three people, intuitively you think "everyone MUST see a blue eyed person" but remember the issue isn't what they can see, it's what they can be sure EVERYONE else can see - so assume everyone is a pessimist and expects their own eye color to be non-blue...

A (think her eyes are brown) looks at B and thinks "B sees me (A) with brown eyes and thinks her(B's) eyes are also brown and so A assumes B assumes C is staring at 2 brown eyed people and expects that her own (C's) eyes are ALSO brown.  And there's the rub... I was stuck for a while on the idea "but A knows for sure that C can see B's blue eyes!!!"... however, the issue isn't what A knows; The issue is what A knows B knows C knows.  And when you walk the chain of deduction, assuming everyone is a pessimist (not wanting to think they have blue eyes) the inevitable conclusion is that every person must deduce that the last person in the he thinks she thinks chain will assume there are NO blue eyed people!

Quite counter intuitively, this progression can work for any number of people, so it doesn't matter if there are 3 or 3 million blue eyed people, it's still entirely logical and rational (actually inevitable) that A will come to the conclusion that person [number of blue eyed people on the island] can reasonably suspect that there are no blue eyed people on the island.  And if there are no blue eyed people on the island then there's no place from which to start one's logical countdown.

If the last person in the logical chain has been informed that there is indeed a blue eyed person on the island then either they will leave (seeing no one else with blue eyes) or they will stay (because they themselves see someone else with blue eyes) and the entire deduction process begins.

Comment: @ YevgenySimkin - Your answer and discussion with @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' was really helpful, thanks! But (I think...) it's still not that 'person n can reasonably suspect that there are no blue eyes on the island', but rather that 'person 0 (me) can reasonably suspect that person 1 can reasonably suspect that person 2 ... can reasonably suspect that person n can reasonably suspect that there are no blue eyes on the island', no?

Comment: Yes - that's what my (possibly overwrought) answer is trying to say. Without the globally heard assertion it's inevtiable that the blue-eyed person has no way to know that they have blue eyes (no matter how many of them there are).

Answer (score 9):

### Does the Guru's statement bring any new information?

The misleading thing here is that you might get tricked into the belief that the statement of the Guru just tells the people on the island that there is someone with blue eyes. But that is nothing new! The people already knew that by looking around.

The statement of the Guru says something deeper. It not only makes the people know that there is someone with blue eyes, it also makes them know that everybody else knows that there is someone with blue eyes.

Even deeper, it makes them know that everybody else knows that everybody else knows that everybody else knows (ad infinitum) that there is someone with blue eyes.

*Now that is a strong statement, because the people themselves only knew this up to a certain point!*

### A small example

For instance suppose that we have 3 blue eyed people, `A`, `B` and `C`, and no Guru. `A` knows that there is someone with blue eyes. `A` knows that `B` knows that there is someone with blue eyes. But `A` does *not* know that `B` knows that `C` knows that there is someone with blue eyes, because `A` doesn't know his own eye color. For this to know, `A` needs the statement of the Guru.

Comment: Everybody knows that there's someone with blue eyes, because everyone can see everyone else. So any given person can see either 99 or 100 blue eyed people. There is no question of somebody not knowing that someone else knows there are blue eyed people or not, as they know everyone can see atleast one blue-eyed person.

Comment: Not in general, read my example again. "But A does **not** know that B knows that C knows that there is someone with blue eyes, because A doesn't know his own eye color."

Comment: Everyone can already see everyone else - it's not like the game of telephone where A can only see B, B can only see C, etc.  The only way A would not know there was someone with blue eyes is if he were the only blue-eyed person, and there are 100.

Comment: Start with 3 persons, not with 100 and do the reasoning again.

Comment: @ChieltenBrinke I don't see the number as relevant.  3 or 100, the only way someone could leave is if they do not see someone with blue eyes, and they leave because the guru said there was a blue-eyed person present (implying it is the person that cannot see blue in the other people around that actually has blue eyes).  When you have more than 1 person with that color, the logic falls apart.

Comment: @vapcguy So you're basically saying, this logic puzzle that fascinates everyone is BS and I refuse to try to understand the solution. Whatever. I can't make it more clear than I already did.

Comment: @ChieltenBrinke Just hard to find the logic where none exists. Logically, everyone already *KNOWS* the others' eye color-they can see everyone else. By that same premise, they *know* everyone else *knows* their color, too. How does that help John Doe to know his own color & leave?  Doesn't make any sense. If someone sees a blue-eyed person and sees they don't leave, yeah, it means they don't know their own color. Neither does anyone else know their color & doesn't mean they will take it upon themselves to believe they're the blue-eyed person and leave & be correct in doing so, if they did.

Comment: @vapcguy It is not difficult to understand the riddle with only two people. Start with that. With three people, the statement "if I have brown eyes the riddle is reduced to the two people variant for the others" is sufficient for most people to accept that the guru's announcement is required, however understanding how it provides additional information is very difficult. The example section of this answer is a probably the easiest explanation for that in the thread.

Comment: @pc3e For me, it never mattered how many people are in the riddle or what the guru said since it doesn't-at least to me-add any new information.  The people still have to figure out if they have blue eyes and leave.  Without a mirror, and without talking, they can't figure that out just because someone doesn't leave.  It's a preposterous supposition, because they can't assume the other person just MUST know they have blue eyes, and because they didn't, *I* MUST have blue eyes and leave.  Under that pretense, both people would see each other still there the next morning and go at the same time.

Comment: @vapcguy They riddle states that the islanders are all _"perfect logicians -- if a conclusion can be logically deduced, they will do it instantly."_ It is further assumed that everyone wants to leave the island, and that everyone knows these facts about the others, to any degree. I'll agree that this makes the exercise very theoretical, but I do think it would work most of the time if you tried it with two random people at a party. It would never work with 100 random people though, probably not even with three. I'll give you that.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to more or less understand the solution only by imagining that this whole story is happening in Island 100 - our island, and there are another 99 islands in the ocean, each called Island 1, Island 2, Island 3, ..., Island 99, each of them named after the total number of people with blue eyes in them. The total number of people in each island is the same: 200.

None of the islanders knows anything at all about the other islands. Actually, for them the other islands might just be a mental construction in their imagination; but for the sake of our reasoning, let's consider them as real islands. Since the islands do not have any sort of communication between them, Island 100 is *exactly* the island of the original problem.

- **Island 1:** 1 blue eyed person, 199 brown eyed people.
- **Island 2:** 2 blue eyed people, 198 brown eyed people.
- **Island 3:** 3 blue eyed people, 197 brown eyed people.
- **Island 4:** 4 blue eyed people, 196 brown eyed people.
- **Island 5:** 5 blue eyed people, 195 brown eyed people.
- ...
- **Island 99:** 99 blue eyed people, 101 brown eyed people.
- **Island 100:** 100 blue eyed people, 100 brown eyed people.

The rules are equal in every island - people will leave when they find out their eye colour.

On a given day, the guru, travelling on a boat, does the same operation in every island.

**On each day *N*, the *N* blue eyed people from Island *N* will leave.**

The fact that the *N-1* blue eyed people seen by any blue eyed observer on any island *didn't* leave the day before convinces that observer that they are *actually* in Island *N*, and not in Island *N-1*. (The only two possible islands they could be in, since each of them knows that there are either *N-1* or *N* blue-eyed people on their island.)

Answer (score 5):

The solution listed is correct, but it is the solution to a much harder problem than you might think, which is:
There are 200 people on an island, where any person can have either blue or non-blue eyes.
On Day 0, a Guru announces either that:
a) I see at least one pair of blue eyes
or
b) I see no blue eyes.

Given this single datum, the standard algorithm would solve ANY number of blue eyes, from 0 to 200. Without this single datum, even though you can see N blue eyes (where N is from 0 to 199), you can never be certain what your eye color is, because you would never know if Total Blue Eyes = N or N+1.

Put another way, if you can see N blue eyes, and the guru tells you that Total Blue Eyes == 0 OR that Total Blue Eyes >= 1 on Day 0, you can determine your own eye color after N-1  days (if you have blue eyes) or N days (if you have non-blue eyes) according to the standard algorithm.

If, however, you were ONLY trying to solve the single case where exactly N people have blue eyes, then you can leave without the Guru on Day 0:

- On Day 0, if you see N blue eyes, your eyes are non-blue. Stay.
- On Day 0, if you see N-1 blue eyes, your eyes are blue. Leave tonight.

What is even cooler is that if you are willing to NOT solve any single case, such as "0 people have blue eyes", then you don't need the Guru to start the induction.

- On Day 0, you see N blue eyes, where N>=0. On day N, if no one has left yet, leave knowing you have blue eyes. If anyone ever leaves before you get a chance, you don't have blue eyes, leave the very next day.

Which is pretty cool considering that if odds of having blue eyes were, say 50%, then the odds of all having blue eyes = 1/2 ^ 200 ~ 10^-61. Pretty tolerable odds if you were lacking a Guru!

It would be cool to see a general algorithm that could be tuned with a variable cost for "days spent calculating" versus a cost for "getting the answer wrong". The default question basically assumes "cost of days spent calculating" == 0 or "cost of getting the answer wrong" == infinity.

Comment: "you don't have blue eyes, leave the very next day." If the only thing you know is that you _don't_ have blue eyes, you don't leave. You only leave when you find out your exact eye colour.

Answer (score 4):

If the oracle said nothing and there was one person, that person could never know if anyone at all had blue eyes, so could not leave.

If there were two, neither would know in the first day whether the other was the only one and should leave alone, or whether they themselves were the second, so neither can leave. Everyone who can see the two knows that those two should not leave.

On the second day, you cannot know if the other should have left yesterday alone or whether you and he should leave today with you. You know he should not leave tomorrow, as there are definitely only one (him) or two (him and you) but since you know he is only here today because he was as clueless as you on day one, you can't determine your own eye colour from this.

On the third day, the two of you know that the other should have left on one of the previous day's, but still do not know which. Everybody else has the same dilemma as you did on the third - you don't know if the two are waiting for you, or simply couldn't work it out the day before. Again there are either two who missed their day yesterday, or three including you.

By the 4th day, everyone knows they've all missed their chance, because they can only see one or two sets of blue, and their own (unknown) would make two or three

Answer (score 4):

With all this logic and chain of thought, one basic but key part of the puzzle is forgotten.
The islanders need to know the **color of their eyes** to leave the island. 
At any point a blue-eyed person can see that there are 99 blue-eyed people and 100 brown-eyed people. And on the 100th day, when 99 blue-eyed people have not left the island, the islander has still not concluded the color of his eyes (maybe blue, brown or **any other color**). 
But, had he known there was at least one blue-eyed person on the island (as proclaimed by the guru), he could have concluded that his eyes had to be blue on the 100th day.
When no one leaves on the 100th day as well(since no one can determine the color of **their** eyes yet), they are left with same information on the 101st day as they had on 1st day, i.e, a blue-eyed person can see 99 blue-eyed people and 100 brown-eyed people. 
Since all islanders are perfect logicians, no islander can come to a conclusion without the guru's proclamation.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing what this answer adds that isn't already in one of the other answers.

Comment: I tried to make an intuitive point that without the guru's proclamation, the islanders are left with the same information they had on the first day even after N numbers of days. Thereby stressing on the necessity of oracle's proclamation without bringing up the N,N-1,N-2 ... logic as  others have rightly pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answer induces from 4 blue eyed people that without the Guru nobody can leave the island.

Although an old topic, I would like to add a bit of explanation.

Some answers postulate that the key information provided by the Guru is the fact that from now on, everybody knows that everybody knows that some people are blue eyed on the island.

Explain how this is news if there were say 100 blue eyed people on the island?? Some mistakenly apply the reasoning that among 100 blue eyed, someone with blue eyes only sees 99 and thinks that the other blue eyed may see only 98 who thinks there may be only 97, and so on down to 1.

The issue here is that people don't think in turn, but simultaneously. If there are 100 people with blue eyes, all blue eyed people see 99 others and know for a fact that everybody else sees at least 98.

**So why on earth do we need the Guru??**

If there are 100 blue eyed people on the island, for any person with blue eyes (who only sees 99 blue eyed people), they need to know it is possible for 99 to leave the island (i.e. if 99 didn't leave yesterday, it must mean that I have blue eyes too). However, for 99 people to leave the island, it needs to be possible for 98. And so on until 1.
So while for any N>3 blue eyed people everyone knows that everyone knows that the island has some blue eyed people, it is necessary to also know that people would be theoretically able to leave the island for any N even if <=3. And by induction this is only possible if 1 person is able to leave the island.

**In conclusion**
For any N>3 the Guru didn't provide any new information as to the presence of blue eyed people on the island.
However, the Guru's declaration makes it theoretically possible for N=1 to leave the island, which is necessary for N=2, and so on for any N.
The Guru's declaration actually triggers a chain of events or non events (people leaving or staying) that in itself bears an information that is critical for the strategy to take place.

I think some other answers and comments point in that direction, I hope mine does a slightly better job at clarifying the importance of the Guru's declaration.

Comment: Well done. I like your reference to starting the inductive process.

Answer (score 4):

Another side of this, instead of doing the induction from 1 person with blue eyes, it may be more intuitive to instead consider induction from the guru's statement.

Before any announcement, all brown-eyed people know that there are either 100 or 101 blue-eyed people on the island, and all blue-eyed people know that there are either 99 or 100 blue-eyed people on the island.

Consider the case that instead of saying she sees someone with blue eyes, she instead said: "**I see at least 100 people with blue eyes**".

Brown-eyed people learn nothing new from this. Blue-eyed people, who only see 99 others, immediately learn their own eyes must be blue, so can leave on the first night.

Next consider the case where the guru states "**I see at least 99 people with blue eyes**".

Now nobody learns anything new initially about their own eye colour. The brown-eyed people, however, had a 1 day information advantage. They also know that nobody will be leaving tonight, as they know that there are not exactly 99 blue-eyed people because they see 100.

After the first night, when all the blue-eyed people are still there, they all simultaneously learn that there are at least 100 blue-eyed people, the same information that the brown-eyed people had the day before, and the same as if the guru had delayed the announcement by a day, but then announced seeing 100.

Similarly, if the guru had stated "**I see at least 98 people with blue eyes**", everyone on the island now knows nobody will leave the first night, as they all see at least 99.

After the first night, the islanders all know that everyone is in the same position as if the guru had just announced "I see at least 99 people with blue eyes". Blue-eyed people now wait to see if the 99 other blue eyed people leave on the second night. Brown-eyed people already know nobody will leave on the second night.

Extending this to $N$, if the guru states "**I see at least $N$ people with blue eyes**", where $N < 99$, blue-eyed people initially know that nobody will leave for at least $99-N$ nights, and brown-eyed people initially know that nobody will leave for $100-N$ nights. In each case the person knows that nobody will leave for a number of nights equal to the difference between the guru's announcement of number of blue-eyed people, and the number of blue-eyed people they see.

After 1 night, everyone knows that nobody left (which for $N<99$ is not a surprise to anyone). This makes the following day equivalent to a day on which the guru had announced "I see $N+1$ people with blue eyes".

---

Returning to what the guru actually said "**I see <s>at least 1 person</s> *someone* with blue eyes**", everyone knows that:

- Nobody will leave the island tonight, or tomorrow night, or indeed for many more weeks.
- Tomorrow the situation will be the same as if the guru had, 1 day later, announced "I see at least 2 people with blue eyes"
- The day after tomorrow, the situation will be the same as if the guru had, 2 days later, announced "I see at least 3 people with blue eyes".

...

- After 98 nights the situation will be the same as if the guru had, 98 days later, announced "I see at least 99 people with blue eyes". The blue-eyed people will have marked this date on their calendar as the date on which they expect to see all the blue-eyed people leave.
- After 99 nights when the blue-eyed people did NOT leave, each blue-eyed person now knows that there are at least 100 blue-eyed people; the 99 they can each see, and by implication themselves. The brown-eyed people, who see 100 blue-eyed people would similarly have marked their calendar with this as they date they expect all the blue-eyed people to leave.
- After 100 days, the blue-eyed people have all left. The remaining brown-eyed people have a strong suspicion they all have brown eyes, but cannot know for sure that they are not the only other green-eyed person apart from the guru, or that they don't have another eye colour entirely (grey, red, purple) that they have never seen in anyone else.

---

A side-observation - if the guru states "I see someone with blue eyes and someone with brown eyes", everyone will be able to leave - each person would diarise two dates - the date on which all the blue-eyed people will leave unless their own eyes are blue, and the date on which all the brown-eyed people will leave unless their own eyes are brown. Only those with a colour specifically mentioned by the guru may leave.

On a similar island with 10 blue-eyed people, 20 brown-eyed and 20 green-eyed, and one grey-eyed:

- an announcement like "eyes of the following colours are present in our population: blue, brown, green, grey" (possibly amended if there are logical loopholes) would lead to the grey-eyed person leaving that very night, the blue-eyed people all leaving on the 10th night, and everyone else leaving on the 20th night.
- an announcement like "I can see someone with [colour] eyes" allows only those with that eye colour to leave, and only after sufficient nights have elapsed so that everyone with that eye colour expected everyone else with that eye colour to have left the previous night.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is the right answer but my wife and I thought everyone will leave the island the 201st day and here's why:

We assumed the Guru would either say " I see a blue eyed person" or " I see a brown eyed person" each day (alternating or randomly, doesnt matter). Since she's a logician too, she would accurately total up the number of brown and blue eyes on day#200. Let's say a person x has brown eyes, she will realize by day # 200 what her eye color is as she knows by now that there are 100 blue colored eyes and 99 brown eyed people. This logic will apply to every member too.

Very interested to see what the geniuses on this forum have to say!

Comment: The problem with this is that none of the islanders (except the blue-eyed ones on the day they leave) know that there are only blue and brown eyes. For all they know, they could be the odd one out with green (or purple, orange, etc.) eyes.

Comment: The Guru does not make multiple pronouncements. Moreover, just because a person one day says "I can see a blue-eyed person" and then another day says "I can see a blue-eyed person", doesn't mean there are two blue-eyed people.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but there's a flaw in the riddle's question that is badly waved away with:

> "Before you email me to argue or question: This solution is correct. My explanation may not be the clearest, and it's very difficult to wrap your head around (at least, it was for me), but the facts of it are accurate. I've talked the problem over with many logic/math professors, worked through it with students, and analyzed from a number of different angles. The answer is correct and proven, even if my explanations aren't as clear as they could be."

How did the islanders come into existance? When and how did they decide, they want to leave? Do they think alike and do they know so?

If they came to be on the island and/or decide to leave, all of them at the same time, they can all leave at the 100th night, because they figured out the even distribution (100 blue, 100 brown eyes) by the same argument as they do with the oracles pronouncement. The situation becomes stable only with some sort of non-beginning. The islanders were always there and didn't know, when the others would've started to count days. This non-beginning is at best implicit in the question.

They must also be thinking alike and know it. Plus they must be thinking in a certain way to come to this solution. The best way to argue this point is the numbering introduced by Ben Millwood: Person 1 might assume that there are only 99 blue eyed people. This is equivalent with the assumption that people 2-100 see 98 blue eyed people. Hence everyone can discard the possibility that there is someone seeing less than 98 blue eyed people. Since they discarded this 98 they can alos skip the nights to count them off. Everyone who sees 98 same colored eyes assembles to leave in night 1. Everyone who sees 99 same colored eyes assembles to leave in night 2. This solution is also valid, logically derivable and requires only another way of thinking alike and knowing the others do so, too. So to make the answer unique you would have to formulate if they want to leave **urgently** or want to know their own eye color **urgently** but stay as long as possible.

I'm not saying the solution is incorrect. I'm just saying it's not the only correct solution, because of implicit assumptions (thinking alike) and missing requirements (leave soon or stay long).

Long story short: You only need the oracle, if there is no other starting point for counting off the nights.

Comment: If everyone had brown eyes, nobody would have any reason to leave, ever.  If only one person had blue eyes, that person would see that everyone else had brown eyes, and would never have any reason to believe himself any different.  If two people had blue eyes, neither would have reason to expect that an inability to see any blue eyes would cause the other to leave, and thus have no reason to believe that the other person could see any blue eyes, etc.

Comment: Your solution is invalid.  Consider; what happens if there actually are 101 brown eyed people and 99 blue eyed people?  In this case the brown eyed people will see exactly the same as what the blue eyed people see in the original formulation.

Comment: The flaw in your argument is this; Person 1 can know that person 2 through 100 sees at least 98 blue eyes.  However he can not know that person 2 through 100 knows that he sees at least 98 blue eyes.

Comment: @supercat except that the guru anounced that there was one blue eyed person.  And the question specifies that everyone believes the guru.

Comment: @Taemyr: I was describing what the situation would be *in the absence of the guru*; I probably should have explicitly said that, but thought that would be implied by the fact that the original supposition (everyone having brown eyes) was contrary to what the guru said.  The real key is that if, in the event that nobody could see any blue eyes, it would be possible for everyone to believe that everyone had brown eyes, *nobody would ever have reason to believe that anyone else's failure to leave would imply anything*, even if everyone arrived at the island at the same moment.

Comment: Finally, a correct "answer". This is not an answer, this explains why the riddle is incorrect. The riddle assumes a stable state before the oracle speaks. That is an incorrect assumption. A more correct "time start" would have been if everyone opens their eyes at the same time. I don't need to stinking oracle to tell me that everyone knows that everyone knows that everyone knows... that there are people with blue eyes on the island. I can see that there are many, I see others looking at them - they know there are many. If there were <3 - OK, I need an oracle. otherwise - no.

Comment: -1 Simply asserting 'The answer is correct and proven', and then failing to prove it, is not enough. Bad wording is no excuse, it is actually the very absence of the asserted proof. Claiming 'I know professors' doesn't help anyone to understand the alleged proof.

Answer (score 2):

I got somewhat similar answer, but logically easier and relying on a "trick".
When the Oracle is about to come all people come to the meeting unless they see that there is a blue eyed already present there. So:
1)If there are no people one goes to the meeting
1.a) if he sees anyone blue eyed coming, then he is brown eyed
1.b) if no one else comes then he is blue-eyed - the oracle will anounce at least him or anybody else blue-eyed and he can't be sure who the oracle is talking about. But if no one else comes, then he is blue eyed and leaves, knowing that.
So all blue eyed will understand they are such in the steps mentioned and the rest that they will stay there forever :)
The main reasoning is - "I won't go to the meeting if I see someone blue-eyed there, because if I'm also blue eyed we won't be able to make the distinction or at least we should fallback to the other solution"
"Wait and see" action is present in both solutions, while in mine the oracle is there only for motivation for the meeting.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  This is an interesting idea but 1) why would you know to follow these rules before the meeting and 2) what does this have to do with why the oracle is needed.  I think this could be better as part of a new but related puzzle.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add an answer to one of the bonus questions:

> Why do they have to wait 99 nights if, on the first 98 or so of these nights, they're simply verifying something that they already know?

Let's break this down into logical reasoning from the perspective of a blue-eyed and a brown eyed person.

### Blue-eyed person perspective

I can see 99 pairs of blue.

**If I'm blue**: blues can see 99 pairs, browns can see 100 pairs.

**If I'm brown**: blues can see 98 pairs, browns can see 99 pairs.

### Brown-eyed person perspective

I can see 100 pairs of blue.

**If I'm blue**: blues can see 100 pairs, browns can see 101 pairs

**If I'm brown**: blues can see 99 pairs, browns can see 100 pairs.

All of this is immediately inferred by everyone else. Then we go down one more layer of reasoning.

### Perspective of blue-eyed person seen by another blue-eyed person, who thinks they might be brown

I can see 98 pairs of blue.

**If I'm blue**: blues can see 98 pairs, browns can see 99 pairs.

**If I'm brown**: blues can see 97 pairs, browns can see 98 pairs.

And one more layer of inference...

### Perspective of the hypothetical person who can only see 97 pairs

I can see 97 pairs of blue.

**If I'm blue**: blues can see 97 pairs, browns can see 98 pairs.

**If I'm brown**: blues can see 96 pairs, browns can see 97 pairs.

---

You get the idea. It seems absurd initially to wait the full 100 days, but because we must consider the full chain of inference for everyone involved, we eventually get down to the same recursive argument and are thus forced to wait for the full 100 days. Everyone *knows* that no one could possibly see less than 98 pairs of blue, but they need the full 100 days to figure out if *they personally* are blue-eyed or brown-eyed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the oracle just tells everybody something they already know, so they seemingly shouldn't be able to deduce anything new from that.

Another way to resolve this is to consider which of the below statements are true:

B1:  At least one native has blue eyes.
B2:  Every native knows B1 is true.
B3:  Every native knows B2 is true.
...
B_(k+1):  Every native knows B_k is true.

And the answer is that, for n blue-eyed natives, statements B_1 through B_n will be true.  And while B_n is true, only the non-blue-eyed natives will know it is true.

When the oracle made the statement, it's not just that everybody heard the statement, so they know B1 is true.  Everybody knows that everybody was there and heard the oracle's statement, so everybody knows B2 is true.  The fact that the statement was made in public makes all the B_k statements true, and B_n is something that some of the natives didn't already know was true.

Answer (score 0):

The Guru's statement provides an arbitrary day that synchronizes everyone's starting point for counting days for blue-eyed people. She really can say anything she wants that will perform this function.

Taking this by cases works for any number of people, and only requires up to 4 days, because it accounts for the logical implications of the fact that the population of blue-eyed people cannot be fewer than the number of blue-eyed people that a blue-eyed person can see. Let me explain:

N = how many blue-eyed people there are. X = how many blue-eyed people I can see.

> ### X = 0, N = 0
>
> There are no blue-eyed people, so the Guru cannot honestly say that there are.

> ### X = 0, N = 1
>
> If I cannot see any blue-eyed people, but the Guru indicates that there are, then I know that I must be the only blue-eyed person, so I will leave the first day.

> ### X = 1, N = 1 or 2
>
> If I can see one person with blue eyes, then there are either 1 or 2 blue-eyed people, depending on whether I myself have blue eyes.
>
> If I do not have blue eyes, then the blue-eyed person cannot see any other blue-eyed people and will know by the Guru's declaration that he himself is the only person with blue eyes, and so will leave the first day. If the blue-eyed person leaves the first day, then I must not have blue eyes.
>
> If I do have blue eyes, then the other blue-eyed person can see only one other blue-eyed person and will expect me to leave the first day if he does not have blue eyes. But once neither he nor I leave the first day, we will know that we both have blue eyes and we will leave the second day.

> ### X = 2, N = 2 or 3
>
> If I can see two people with blue eyes, then there are either 2 or 3 people with blue eyes, depending on whether I myself have blue eyes.
>
> If I do not have blue eyes, then any blue-eyed person (A) can see only 1 other blue-eyed person and knows that there are either 1 or 2 blue-eyed people. Person A also knows that the other blue-eyed person (B) can see either 0 or 1 blue-eyed people, so A knows that B knows that there are either (0 or 1) or (1 or 2) blue-eyed people. But A knows for a fact that there exists at least 1 person with blue eyes, so he can discount any situations where fewer than 1 blue-eyed person exist.
>
> If I do have blue eyes, then another blue-eyed person can also see only 2 blue-eyed people and knows that there are either 2 or 3 blue-eyed people.
>
> The actual options from any point of view include 1, 2, or 3 people with blue eyes. But since I can see 2 with blue eyes, I know that there cannot be only 1, so I can discount the N=1 situation.
>
> On the first day, those who can see only 1 blue-eyed person will expect them to leave. But because I know that there are at least 2, I expect no one to leave.
>
> On the second day, those who can see 1 blue-eyed person will have realized that they also have blue eyes and will leave. We who can see 2 will know that the N=1 situation can be discounted, but cannot discount the N=2 unless no one leaves the second day.
>
> If no one leaves the second day, then I will know that I must also have blue eyes, and we will all leave on the third day.

> ### X = 3, N = 3 or 4
>
> If I can see three people with blue eyes, then there are either 3 or 4 people with blue eyes, depending on whether I myself have blue eyes.
>
> If I do not have blue eyes, then any blue-eyed person (A) can see only 2 other blue-eyed people and knows that there are either 2 or 3 blue-eyed people. Person A also knows that a blue-eyed person (B) can see either 1 or 2 blue-eyed people, so A knows that B knows that there are either (1 or 2) or (2 or 3) blue-eyed people. But A knows for a fact that there exists at least 2 people with blue eyes, so he can discount any situations where fewer than 2 blue-eyed people exist.
>
> If I do have blue eyes, then another blue-eyed person can also see only 3 blue-eyed people and knows that there are either 3 or 4 blue-eyed people.
>
> The options from any point of view include 2, 3, or 4 people with blue eyes. As with the previous situation, everyone knows that there are at least 2 blue-eyed people, so I can dismiss the N=1 case.
>
> On the first day, no one expects anyone to leave. I know that a blue-eyed person A (who knows that N=2 or N=3) knows that a blue-eyed person B (who knows that N=1 or N=2) doesn't know whether B should leave today.
>
> On the second day, no one expects anyone to leave. I know that A knows that if B can see 1, then B will realize that he has blue eyes and leave today.
>
> On the third day, I know that A would learn that B can also see 2 blue-eyed people, so A must have blue eyes, and A would leave today.
>
> On the fourth day, I will confirm that A can also see 3 blue-eyed people, which means I must also have blue eyes, so I will leave today.
>
> Those who can see 4 blue-eyed people will know that they themselves do not have blue eyes on the fifth day.

> ### X = 4, N = 4 or 5
>
> If I can see four people with blue eyes, then there are either 4 or 5 people with blue eyes, depending on whether I myself have blue eyes.
>
> If I do not have blue eyes, then any blue-eyed person (A) can see only 3 other blue-eyed people and knows that there are either 3 or 4 blue-eyed people. Person A also knows that a blue-eyed person (B) can see either 2 or 3 blue-eyed people, so A knows that B knows that there are either (2 or 3) or (3 or 4) blue-eyed people. But A knows for a fact that there exists at least 3 people with blue eyes, so he can discount any situations where fewer than 3 blue-eyed people exist.
>
> If I do have blue eyes, then another blue-eyed person can also see only 4 blue-eyed people and knows that there are either 4 or 5 blue-eyed people.
>
> The options from any point of view include 3, 4, or 5 people with blue eyes. As with the previous situation, everyone knows that there are at least 3 blue-eyed people, so I can dismiss the N=1 and N=2 cases.
>
> On the first day, no one expects anyone to leave. I know that a blue-eyed person A (who knows that N=3 or N=4) knows that a blue-eyed person B (who knows that N=2 or N=3) doesn't know whether B should leave today.
>
> On the second day, no one expects anyone to leave. I know that A knows that if B can see 2, then B will realize that he has blue eyes and leave today.
>
> On the third day, I know that A would learn that B can also see 3 blue-eyed people, so A must have blue eyes, and A would leave today.
>
> On the fourth day, I will confirm that A can also see 4 blue-eyed people, which means I must also have blue eyes, so I will leave today.
>
> Those who can see 5 blue-eyed people will know that they do not have blue eyes on the fifth day.

> ### General case: X > 3
>
> If I can see X blue-eyed people, then there are either X or X+1 blue-eyed people, depending on whether I myself also have blue eyes.
>
> If I do not have blue eyes, then any blue-eyed person (A) can see only X-1 blue-eyed people and knows that there are either X-1 or X blue-eyed people. This person also knows that any (other) blue-eyed person (B) can see either X-2 or X-1 blue-eyed people and knows that there are either (X-2 or X-1) or (X-1 or X) blue-eyed people.
>
> If I do have blue eyes, then any other blue-eyed person can also see only X blue-eyed people and also knows that there are either X or X+1 blue-eyed people.
>
> I know that the full list of options from some blue-eyed person's point of view are X-2, X-1, X, or X+1. But I know that X-2 and X-1 are not actual options, because of my own knowledge that there are either X or X+1 blue-eyed people.
>
> I also know that some blue-eyed person's knowledge of the options from his point of view, relative to my point of view, are X-2, X-1, or X. But he knows that X-2 is not an actual option, because of his own knowledge that there are either X-1 or X blue-eyed people.
>
> If there were X-2 blue-eyed people, they should leave on the first day, but since I know there aren't that many, I do not expect anyone to do anything then. I know that a blue-eyed person A knows that a blue-eyed person B has to wait for no one to leave for B to be convinced that B has blue eyes, so A expects no one to leave, either.
>
> If there were X-1 blue-eyed people, they should leave on the second day, but I know there aren't that many, so I do not expect anyone to do anything then, either. I also know that a blue-eyed person A knows that if a blue-eyed person B has been convinced that B has blue eyes, then B will leave today, so A has to wait to see whether B leaves before A will be convinced that A has blue eyes. Thus A will wait through the second day.
>
> If there are X blue-eyed people, they should leave on the third day, and if they do, then I know that I do not have blue eyes. I know that if a blue-eyed person A has become convinced that A has blue eyes, then he would leave today.
>
> If there are X+1 blue-eyed people, then no one will have left on the third day, so I will know that I have blue eyes, and I will leave the fourth day. I know that if a blue-eyed person A has not left yesterday, it must be because he can also see X blue-eyed people, which means that I must also have blue eyes.
>
> Anyone who has another eye color will know that they do not have blue eyes by the fifth day, after all the blue-eyed people have left.

Without the Guru's synchronization, everyone's "day-counter" will be unknown to anyone else, so no one can know when to expect anyone else to leave.

Comment: Your logic is wrong, starting at this part: "If I do not have blue eyes, then any blue-eyed person can see only 3 other blue-eyed people and knows that there are either 3 or 4 blue-eyed people. This person also knows that any other blue-eyed person can see only 3 blue-eyed people and knows that there are either 3 or 4 blue-eyed people." That person does not know that any other blue-eyed person can see 3 blue-eyed people, because that person does not know their own eye color. That person only knows that each other blue-eyed person sees 2 or 3 blue-eyed people.

Comment: @f'' Thanks for the critique. I have updated the reasoning. Is this better?

Comment: You're still wrong for the same reason. A blue-eyed person who sees X-1 blue-eyed people does not know that each of those people sees X-1 blue-eyed people.

Comment: You're ignoring the effect of the addition of my own knowledge about the situation. I can see X blue-eyed people, so I know that a blue-eyed person A can see at least X-1 blue-eyed people, and I also know that A knows that (another) blue-eyed person B can see at least X-2 blue-eyed people, and because ***I*** know that there are at least X blue-eyed people and I know that A knows that there cannot be fewer than X-1 blue-eyed people, I need not consider further cases.

Comment: From your X=3 case, if I have blue eyes and I see three people who have blue eyes, we will leave on day 4. But from your X=4 case, if I don't have blue eyes and I see four people who have blue eyes, they will leave on day 3. This is a contradiction.

Comment: The sentence you added in the latest edit "I know that A knows that if B can see 2, then B will realize that he has blue eyes and leave [on the second day]." is false.

Comment: @f'' It is not false, because A and B are theoretical (because they exist in my mind) and know that the minimum number of blue-eyed people is the number or blue-eyed people that everyone knows that a blue-eyed person knows that a blue-eyed person can see.

Comment: If you assume that A and B know that, you end up with false results. Can you answer what happens (who leaves when) in this scenario: four people with blue eyes and one with brown eyes are on the island when the oracle makes the statement.

Comment: @f'' everyone can skip 3 days because they know that everyone else will see at least 3 people with blue eyes. So for the 100 blue eyed scenario they will skip 98 days.